# How to get collection name from a Mongoose model object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose model like so:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let schema = new Schema({
    test: String
}, {
    collection: "test"
});

let model = mongoose.model("TestModel", schema);
```

How do I retrieve the collection name if in a callback I only have access to the "model" reference.

Expecting something like:

```
model.getCollectionName();
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just use :

```
model.collection.collectionName
```

You also have a lot of usefull informations in `model.collection` such as collection options.

Comment: API reference for `Model.prototype.collection`: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-collection

Now I wish there was a reference of the collection itself... Man mongoose docs are some special kind of shitty.

Comment: The collection object is from the MongoDB Node.js driver. There is an API reference for it here: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/6.3/classes/Collection.html